# Does a group hull operator give rise to an idempotent functor?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

I'm working on torsion-free groups, especially on a modification of the proof of the well-known theorem, that every torsion-free group can be embedded in a group, s.t. any two non-trivial elements are conjugate, see [Embedding theorems for groups](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0102.26401), Theorem III.
I find, that by modifying the HNN-extensions for their Corollary 1, by taking for every ordered pair of non-trivial elements countably infinite many, pairwise different, stable letters, instead of just one, that this modified construction gives up to group isomorphism a unique group $\mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,G$ for every torsion-free group $G$.
Utilizing Corollary 6.7 of [Word problems, embeddings, and free
products of right-ordered groups with amalgamated subgroup](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1239.06010), the theorem of Burns-Hale and some further lemmas, I can show, that for the case of torsion-free groups $G$ with a left order, there is also a left order on $\mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,G$. I use this result to show, that every group with left order can be embedded in a group with left order, that does not act on $\mathbb{R}$, and that for all groups of cardinality $|G|\le |\mathbb{R}|$, such a group with cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$ exists. It is the topic of my thesis, that is based on [Left-orderable groups that don’t act on the line](https://zbmath.org/?q=mann%20groups%20act%20on%20the%20line) by K. Mann.

I can summarize the properties of $\mathrm{cl}_{\star}$ as follows:

i) **(Extensivity)** For all torsion-free groups $G$, it follows, that $G\hookrightarrow \mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,G$.

ii) **(Monotonicity)** For all torsion-free groups $G,H$, where $H\hookrightarrow G$, it follows, that $\mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,H\hookrightarrow \mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,G$.

iii) **(Idempotence)** For all torsion-free groups $G$, it follows, that $\mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,\mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,G \cong \mathrm{cl}_{\star}\,G$.

From these properties, I considered calling it a group hull operator.
I want to understand the result and looked into literature, where I found [Idempotent functors and localizations in categories of modules and Abelian groups](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257607325_Idempotent_functors_and_localizations_in_categories_of_modules_and_Abelian_groups), although I did not read it entirely. From that, I considered regarding $\mathfrak{Grp}_{\hookrightarrow}^{\infty}\subset \mathfrak{Grp}$, the category of torsion-free groups with embeddings as arrows, as where my construction lives. I wondered, if it can be termed functorial.

On page 341, the authors define an *idempotent coaugmentation functor* as a *coaugmentation functor* $(L,f)$ for a given category $\mathcal{C}$, where $L$ is a endofunctor and $f: 1_{\mathcal{C}}\to L$ a natural transformation, s.t. $f_{LX}$ and $Lf_{X}$ coincide and are isomorphisms.

Furthermore on page 341, Proposition 6.1, the authors proove, that a functor $L$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is an idempotent functor iff for every object $X$, there exists a morphism $f_{X}:X\to LX$, s.t. for any morphism $\alpha: X\to Z$, where $Z\cong LY$ for some object $Y$, there exists a unique morphism $\beta: LX\to Z$ with $\beta f_{X}=\alpha$.

From the details I've given, it follows, that such a morphism $\beta$ always exists in my case. But concerning its uniqueness, I found out, that there are $X,Z$, s.t. there are several subgroups of $Z$ that are all isomorphic to $LX$ and contain the same subgroup $X$.

This seems to be a major obstruction, am I right? Is there maybe a related concept that fits me better? Any help is appreciated.

**edit:** Looking further into literature, I found [Bounded equivalence of hull classes in Archimedean lattice-ordered groups with unit](https://zbmath.org/?q=Bounded%20Equivalence%20of%20Hull%20Classes%20in%20Archimedean%20Lattice-Ordered%20Groups%20with%20Unit), which seems to fit me better. To wrap it up, the issues with uniqueness of the morphism $\beta$ cannot be overcome, as far as I understood. Thus, it seems that without the uniqueness property, it is not functorial in the sense mentioned, answering the question *Does a group hull operator give rise to an idempotent functor?* indefinite.